# Type safe lookup on heterogeneous lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, type-level-computation

I want to develop a type safe lookup function for the following data type:

```
data Attr (xs :: [(Symbol,*)]) where
   Nil  :: Attr '[]
   (:*) :: KnownSymbol s => (Proxy s, t) -> Attr xs -> Attr ('(s , t) ': xs)
```

The obvious lookup function would be like:

```
 lookupAttr :: (KnownSymbol s, Lookup s env ~ 'Just t) => Proxy s -> Attr env -> t
 lookupAttr s ((s',t) :* env')
       = case sameSymbol s s' of
            Just Refl -> t
            Nothing   -> lookupAttr s env'
```

where `Lookup` type family is defined in singletons library. This definition fails to type check on GHC 7.10.3 with the following error message:

```
 Could not deduce (Lookup s xs ~ 'Just t)
   from the context (KnownSymbol s, Lookup s env ~ 'Just t)
      bound by the type signature for
             lookupAttr :: (KnownSymbol s, Lookup s env ~ 'Just t) =>
                           Proxy s -> Attr env -> t
```

This message is generated for the recursive call `lookupAttr s env'`. This is reasonable, since we have that if

```
Lookup s ('(s',t') ': env) ~ 'Just t
```

holds, and

```
s :~: s'
```

isn't provable, then

```
Lookup s env ~ 'Just t
```

must hold. My question is, how can I convince Haskell type checker that this is indeed true?

Comment: Where is `sameSymbol` defined? Is that from the singletons library as well?

Comment: Oh, nevermind. Found it in [GHC.TypeLits](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html).

Comment: When using strings to represent bound variables, you pay a significant price  in the complexity of your language implementation. Capture-avoiding substitution and alpha-equivalence are both notoriously tricky to get right, not to mention the cost of battling with `Symbol`'s rather janky implementation in GHC. If you're building a type-safe embedded DSL I think you should seriously consider [HOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_abstract_syntax) as a simpler alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Lookup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.1/docs/src/Data-Singletons-Prelude-List.html) is defined in terms of `:==` equality, which comes from [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.1/docs/Data-Singletons-Prelude-Eq.html). Roughly, `Lookup` is implemented this way:

```
type family Lookup (x :: k) (xs :: [(k, v)]) :: Maybe v where
  Lookup x '[] = Nothing
  Lookup x ('(x' , v) ': xs) = If (x :== x') (Just v) (Lookup x xs)
```

Pattern matching on `sameSymbol s s'` doesn't give us any information about `Lookup s env`, and doesn't let GHC reduce it. We need to know about `s :== s'`, and for that we need to use the [singleton version](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.1/docs/Data-Singletons-Prelude-Eq.html#v:-37-:-61--61-) of `:==`.

```
data Attr (xs :: [(Symbol,*)]) where
   Nil  :: Attr '[]
   (:*) :: (Sing s, t) -> Attr xs -> Attr ('(s , t) ': xs)

lookupAttr :: (Lookup s env ~ 'Just t) => Sing s -> Attr env -> t
lookupAttr s ((s', t) :* env') = case s %:== s' of
  STrue  -> t
  SFalse -> lookupAttr s env'
```

Generally, you shouldn't use `KnownSymbol`, `sameSymbol`, or any of the stuff in `GHC.TypeLits` because they're too "low-level" and don't play along with `singletons` by default.

Of course, you can write your own `Lookup` and other functions, and don't need to use the `singletons` imports; what matters is that you synchronize term level and type level, so that term level pattern matching produces relevant information for type level.

Comment: Looks like a lot has changed in the singletons package since this answer was posted. The equality operators have lost the leading `:` which now collides with Prelude. I also haven't really found `STrue/SFalse` for that matter. These seem to have been renamed as well.