# More on type safe lookup for heterogeneous lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, type-level-computation

I'm trying to have some fun with dependently typed programming in Haskell, more specifically with type safe lookup operation. [Previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358347/type-safe-lookup-on-heterogeneous-lists-in-haskell), I've asked about how to implement a lookup operation for the following data type:

```
data Attr (xs :: [(Symbol,*)]) where
   Nil  :: Attr '[]
   (:*) :: (Sing s, t) -> Attr xs -> Attr ('(s , t) ': xs)
```

And I've got the answer:

```
lookupAttr :: (Lookup s env ~ 'Just t) => Sing s -> Attr env -> t
lookupAttr s ((s', t) :* env') = case s %:== s' of
   STrue  -> t
   SFalse -> lookupAttr s env'
```

That works fine. Now, I want to define a heterogeneous list of values of typed syntax, represented by type `Exp`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, TypeFamilies, DataKinds, TypeOperators, PolyKinds #-}
import Data.Singletons.Prelude.List
import Data.Singletons.Prelude.Bool
import Data.Singletons.Prelude.Eq

data Exp (env :: [(Symbol,*)]) :: * -> * where
   Value :: String -> Exp env String
   Var :: (Lookup s env ~ 'Just t) => Sing s -> Exp env t
   Op :: Exp env t -> Exp env t -> Exp env t
```

The heterogeneous list type is defined by `Env` data type:

```
data Env (env :: [(Symbol,*)]) where
  Nil  :: Env '[]
  Cons :: (Lookup s' env ~ 'Nothing) =>
         (Sing s' ,
          Exp ('(s', a) ': env) a) ->
         Env env ->
         Env ('( s',a) ': env)
```

Using these data types, I define a lookup function using some sort of existential quantification (type `Ex2`):

```
data Ex2 (p :: k -> k' -> *) where
   Ex2 :: p e i -> Ex2 p

lookupEnv :: Lookup s env ~ 'Just t => Sing s -> Env env -> Ex2 Exp
lookupEnv s (Cons (s',e) env)
    = case s %:== s' of
         STrue -> Ex2 e
         SFalse -> lookupEnv s env
```

So far, so good. Now, I arrive at some interesting problems:

1) Is there a way to define `lookupEnv` without use this kind of existential quantification provided by type `Ex2`?

2) Suppose that I want to define a operation for modifying a giving entry in a value of type `Env`. The obvious attempt to define this function is

```
modifyEnv :: Lookup s env ~ 'Just t => Sing s -> Exp env t -> Env env -> Env env
modifyEnv s e (Cons (s',e') env')
     = case s %:== s' of
          STrue -> Cons (s', Op e e') env'
          SFalse -> Cons (s',e') (modifyEnv s e env')
```

Function `modifyEnv` compose some expression with another in the environment.
This function isn't accepted by GHC which returns a cryptic error message. How could I define such modification function?

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is not a full solution because it doesn't use a `Symbol`-indexed `Env`ironment, but it might give you a good starting point. I am using a "typed de Bruijn index into a context" type instead:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, TypeFamilies, DataKinds, TypeOperators #-}

data Var (ctx :: [*]) :: * -> * where
    Here :: Var (a ': ctx) a
    There :: Var ctx a -> Var (b ': ctx) a

data Exp (ctx :: [*]) :: * -> * where
    Value :: String -> Exp ctx String
    Var :: Var ctx t -> Exp ctx t
    Op :: Exp ctx t -> Exp ctx t -> Exp ctx t

data Env (ctx :: [*]) where
    Nil :: Env '[]
    Cons :: Exp (a ': ctx) a -> Env ctx -> Env (a ': ctx)
```

This allows writing a typed version of `lookupEnv`, like so:

```
lookupEnv :: Env ctx -> Var ctx t -> Exp ctx t
lookupEnv (Cons e env) v = case v of
    Here -> e
    There v -> weaken $ lookupEnv env v
```

by making it possible to write the following weakening function:

```
weaken :: Exp ctx t -> Exp (a ': ctx) t
weaken (Value s) = Value s
weaken (Var v) = Var (There v)
weaken (Op f e) = Op (weaken f) (weaken e)
```

It seems to me that with using `Symbol`-indexed contexts, it is this last, `weaken`ing step that fails, because `Lookup s ctx ~ Nothing` doesn't seem to have enough structure for GHC to prove what you'd need for `weaken` (that you can shift the context since you know there's not going to be a shadowing issue).

Comment: Hi @Cactus! Thanks for your answer! I've already considered using typed DeBruijn indexes but they are a bit complicated to build by hand for EDSL users (my ultimate goal, is to build a EDSL). Because of that, I'm trying to use Symbol indexed environments.